# I need a C# function to return the last N items entered in a MongoDB database

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I need to implement a function that does exactly this:

```
db.foo.find().sort({date:1}).limit(50);
```

but I have no idea how to do it in C#, using the MongoDB.Driver. I tried to read the documentation for hours, but it's so messy and confusing and I can't get anything to work.

The function should be as follows:

```
// Function to find last N entries
public string[] lastNEntries(int N)
{
    // Get the last N entries of the "text" key as a string array
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Can people please tell me what am I doing wrong before downvoting me? Thanks.

Comment: I haven't downvoted you, but i could tell what, are you doing wrong: SO is not code generation portal, you should show what are you doing and what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something like:

```
        var client = new MongoClient();
        var db = client.GetDatabase("dataBase");
        var msgs = db.GetCollection<Entity>("collection");

        //if you need a filter too
        var filter = Builders<Entity>.Filter.Gt("date",new DateTime(2001,1,1));
        var sort = Builders<Entity>.Sort.Descending("date");
        List<Entity> result = await msgs.Find(filter).Sort(sort).Limit(50).ToListAsync();
```

(entity is just some kind of class with the appropriate structure)